# How can I create a Custom Model Coverter with Freezed in Flutter to this model?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How can I create a Custom Model Coverter with Freezed in Flutter to this model?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sample here:

```dart
@freezed
class ContactAccount with _$ContactAccount {
  const factory ContactAccount({
    required int id,
    String? accountNumber,
    String? bank,
    num? stateId,
  }) = _ContactAccount;

  factory ContactAccount.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => 
      _$ContactAccountFromJson(json);
}
```

To know more about `freezed` check out the link below:

https://pub.dev/packages/freezed